# Can a value returned by a function cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, heap-memory, stack-overflow

So, I have the following code where I have a class **x** on the **heap** and I return its **value**. Let's say that if `res` would be declared on the stack, it would cause a stack overflow. Then, in the code below, since I am returning the **value** stored on the heap, will it cause a stack overflow? Do I have to return a pointer to **x**?

```
x func ()
{
   x* res = new x;
   // code
   return *res;
}

int main ()
{
   x* s = new x;
   *s = func();
}
```

**Also**, I know I didn't `delete` the string.

**EDIT:** Changed from `std::string` to `class x`.

Comment: The space for the return value is allocated before the function is called. Note that a `std::string` doesn't contain a string, only a pointer to one. So it's always the same size.

Comment: Oh, true, it probably wasn't the best example... I'll change.

Comment: I don't see a problem here other than an invalid return type. Did you mean `x *func() {...}`?

Comment: It looks awfully leaky, though.

Comment: No, most likely it will not cause any problems. Stack overflow occurs when your application stack has less capacity (typically it is few MB - so quite a lot) than the amount of data you currently need, so unless your `X` is some extremely large structure, there is no problem (note that all kinds of arrays, strings, containers etc. just store the pointers to dynamically allocated memory).

Comment: @FredLarson Yeah, I know, I only made this code for the question. It doesn't look like this in the real program

Comment: @pptaszni oh, **every** type of STL container is just a pointer? Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @H-005 all except `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on my comment. Normally this should not cause stack overflow if `sizeof(X)`, where `X` is your type, is not extremely large - which it should not be in the well designed application.

However, you could play a bit with your example and check what will happen in case of large data structure:

```
// very bad 1MB structure
struct X
{
  char data[1024*1024];
};

int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(X) << std::endl;
  auto x = foo();
  // data[0] is undefined, printing to prevent compiler from optimizing it out
  std::cout << x.data[0] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now run it with valgrind and set the stacksize to less than 1MB:

```
valgrind --main-stacksize=1000000 --leak-check=full --log-file=vg.valgrind ./xxx
```

You might get the output similar to this:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFEEFFB60
Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffeeff000
```

Note: the overflow is caused by the function call itself, not by storing the returned value, this example would be enough:

```
int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

however, gcc with `-O1` or higher will optimize it out if `foo` does not have any side effects. You can compile with `-O0` to see overflow in simplified example.

Simple improvement to `struct X` to avoid allocating big amount of data on the stack:

```
struct X
{
  X(): data(1024*1024, 'x') {}
  std::string data;
};
```

Comment: Notice that the stack overflow will not occur upon return from the function but upon calling, as the room required for the function is allocated upfront.

Comment: In your example you store the returned object in automatic storage. I think OP already knows that automatic storage can overflow the stack. I think it is more important whether the return value alone can overflow the stack which your example cannot demonstrate because it overflows the stack regardless.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a value returned by a function cause a stack overflow?

Return value can be stored on the stack. Anything that is stored on the stack can cause a stack overflow if it is larger than fits on the stack.

In an example call convention, the caller allocates the stack space for the return value, and parameters are stored after it, in which case if the return value overflows the stack, then that happens before the function is even called.

> ... will it cause a stack overflow?

Potentially, yes. Here is a demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daca31b6551d1be5

Stack overflow is not guaranteed if there is optimisation involved which avoid creation of the temporary object. Same example with optimisation enabled: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11fd38960fd62155

> Do I have to return a pointer to x?

If `sizeof` of the type is very large, then you should avoid returning it by value just as much as you should avoid declaring variables with automatic storage, or creating temporary objects, or passing as value arguments.

In this example a `std::unique_ptr` would probably be a good choice.